# In iOS, is there a difference between adding a view as a subview versus assigning a view to the view property?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I'm trying to make sense of any ambiguities in iOS programming so I've seen tutorials where developers assign their main view to the view property of the viewController like so:

```
let sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: self.view.frame)
view = sceneView
```

However I've also seen developers add their main view as a subview to the view property like so:

```
let sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: self.view.frame)
view.addSubView(sceneView)
```

Are these two processes identical or are they different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not identical but functionally they are similar.  Here's a demonstration of the difference:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    let sceneView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view.addSubview(sceneView)
}
```

In the debugger:

[image: subview]

Compare to replacing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    let sceneView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view = sceneView
}
```

In the debugger:

[image: subview]

So you see that though it's hidden by the subview, the original blue view is still in the view hierarchy when sceneView is added as a subview.  When you replace the view though, the original blue view is no longer part of the view hierarchy at all.

Note: If you want to set the view in loadView() instead of replacing in viewDidLoad() as rmaddy suggested something like this would work.  The trick is getting the proper frame -- if you're in a Navigation Controller for example the frame will be different.

```
override func loadView() {
    let sceneView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view = sceneView
}
```

Comment: that make sense but which process is a better practice or should this process be the least of my worries as a developer?

Comment: Honestly it doesn't matter very much either way.  Replacing the view with your own view technically results in a simpler view hierarchy, so I would generally recommend that approach, but I don't know that Apple has an official stance on it.

Comment: Do not reassign `view` in `viewDidLoad`. If you wish to assign a custom view to the `view` property, override `loadView` and do it there.

Comment: Replacing a view controller's view directly is a bad idea. Just for example, that means that the view's reference count drops to zero, causing it to be released. That in turn causes subviews to be released. All IBOutlets (Which are weak implicitly unwrapped optionals by default) will also be released, so the next time you try to reference an outlet, you will crash because the implicit unwrapping will fail. Do what rmaddy says, and override `loadView` to load a custom view hierarchy.

Comment: I think in the case where you are replacing the view entirely, you want and expect the old, replaced view to be released.  You would not replace a view that had subviews or subviews referenced as IBOutlets either.  In a case like that you'd just add your subview programmatically (WKWebView is a common example of this).

Comment: What about, why do developers instantiate their object inside of the loadView or ViewDidLoad methods?  Don't we lose reference to that lose that instantiated object once either one of those methods has finished executing?

Comment: iOS uses reference counting.  When the method exits its scope, any memory that doesn't have a reference count > 0 is released and reclaimed.  When you set the view reference on the view controller to your new view in loadView, or you add your view as a subView in viewDidLoad, you're incrementing the reference count on your new view so it won't be released.

Comment: @DavidShaw so when the viewController is removed from the screen of the app or the window, does this mean all of the objects that were instantiated or referenced to are released from memory?